# Unable to use intercept-url while using Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I was making some changes to `security.xml` regarding the access like:

```xml
<intercept-url pattern="/app/admin/projectform*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_ENGAGEMENT_MANAGER"/>
```

But I am confused how to differentiate between the following two URLs:

```
/userform?create=Engagement&method=add&from=list
/userform?create=manager&method=add&from=list
```

They need to be assigned to different roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do something very similar but couldn't. On inspecting the source code I realised spring-security doesn't consider request parameters when applying coarse grain/url authorization.

I ended up creating two separate urls.

Comment: i did the same.. thanx.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. <del>I debugged and  found out that `Spring` failed to `parse` separated `roles` with `comma` actually it throws `ParseException` at `doParseExpession. you can find the exact line [here][1]

It says it missing some data if there is a`comma`. I haven't figure why. But, it seems that @Oliver advice is a good one for now. i.e break the rules for two/more lines</del>

## Edit

### Solution:

seems that in `version 4` `filter-security-metadata-source` expect to get `request-matcher` **AND** `use-expressions` i.e try:

```
<filter-security-metadata-source request-matcher="ant" use-expressions="false">
        <intercept-url pattern="/app/admin/projectform*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_ENGAGEMENT_MANAGER"/>
 </filter-security-metadata-source>
```